# Can I provide a download button for content in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iPhone application called IYoga-Classic which will provide high quality videos for Yogs instructions. I want to add a download option to the videos so that the users can download their desired positions even when they are offline? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways, but without knowing more about the architecture of your application I can't be too specific with a response. Basically, have your application fetch the video data from a server and write it out to a file on the iPhone. If you have a more detailed or specific question, you may want to include it.

Comment: Agreed, this is very much an application-specific question, so it's difficult to answer without more details.

Comment: There are 14 positions having 2 difficulty levels. when you click on the image preview a segmented control pops up asking you to choose your difficulty level.(Level 1 0r Level 2)
Clicking on the level will play the desired video. Now is there any way to provide a "download button" so that the videos can be downloaded so that ppl can view it offline?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Make a button, and in its action, download the content. Later, when the user goes to view it, see if it's already downloaded and show it if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the process as easy as possible for users - when they choose to watch a video you could include an option to keep for viewing offline - you could also ask them after then have finished watching the video if they would like to store the video on their device for faster viewing next time etc.

As for the ways you can do this - the best way is to just cache the data and store it locally in a cache directory you can create.